# Is there a way to implement emoticon packs into HTML?

Tags: html

I am making a social networking site and would like emoticons to be available to users to click, and view a whole range of standard emoticons. I have seen around the web, and have not come up with any concrete information whether this can be done, and how.

The way I imagine the emoticons to be is similar to what WhatsApp have adopted. An emoticon icon, which, on click, displays a whole range of icons. Just wondering whether it is possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, you would need a java-script widget for it though and depending on the rest of your framework it could be fully integrated or it would require some additional files.

Here is one example of such a widget, not sure if it is precisely what you need but you can get the idea there:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoticons-js

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you can have a set of icons what you can display?

Or use the unicode entry points for the emojis?
http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Then you need one element with some onclick handler in Javascript which opens up a floating div showing a selection of emojis.